# Why does the block of code under "else:" trigger even though seemingly if statements above are true?

Tags: python

Why does the block of code under "else:" all the way at the bottom trigger even when one of the if statements above are true on the same indentation? Basically no matter what input gets put in with the input function the else statement is always triggered.

Here is the code:

```
car_state = 'stopped'
game_on = True


while game_on:
    command = input('> ')
    if command.lower() == 'stop':
        if car_state == 'stopped':
            print('The car is already not running')
        else:
            print('The car halts to a stop')
            car_state = 'stopped'

    if command.lower() == 'start':
        if car_state == 'stopped':
            print('The car starts vroom')
            car_state = 'running'
        else:
            print('The car is already running')

    if command.lower() == 'help':
        print('''
               start
               stop
               help
               quit

               ''')
    if command.lower() == 'quit':
        game_on = False
    else:
        print('I dont understand that. Type help for commands')
```

I tried to remove the else statements from inside the block from the if statements, but it did not fix it.

Comment: The `else` only applies to the `if` before it... So as long as the `command` is different than `quit` it will trigger. If you want it to apply to ***all*** conditions, change the `if`s to `elif`s

Comment: as long as that last if condition exist, it's going to print that else part because python will consider as the else of the if == 'quit' condition.

Answer (score 1):

With this code you go through all if statement.
Once arrived at the last one, the input is not " quit " so you go always in the "else" case.

```
car_state = 'stopped'
game_on = True


while game_on:
    command = input('> ')
    if command.lower() == 'stop':
        if car_state == 'stopped':
            print('The car is already not running')
        else:
            print('The car halts to a stop')
            car_state = 'stopped'

    elif command.lower() == 'start':
        if car_state == 'stopped':
            print('The car starts vroom')
            car_state = 'running'
        else:
            print('The car is already running')

    elif command.lower() == 'help':
        print('''
               start
               stop
               help
               quit

               ''')
    elif command.lower() == 'quit':
        game_on = False
    else:
        print('I dont understand that. Type help for commands')
```

try with "elif", so that the only possibility to go in the final "else" is to fail all the previous if/elif statement